# VBA extend range of chart by a variable stored in a cell

Tags: vba, charts, range, axis

This is proper basic but I'm struggling here. I need the range of rows of a data source in a graph to extend or retract by a value I have in "J5". "J5" changes dynamically and I can use a call function for it to work in the graph. Because of the way the charts are set up it has to be this way. My code so far is:

```
Sub Updatecodelengh()

Dim i As Integer
Dim G As Worksheet

Set G = Sheet1
i = G.Range("J5")

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GanttChart").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(16).Values = "='Gantt'!$L$3:$L$4"

End Sub
```

Where it says "='Gantt'!$L$3:$L$4" I need the range of the chart data to start on $L$3 and extend downwards by the value obtained in J5. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean simply

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(16).Values = "='Gantt'!$L$3:$L$" & i
```

However, you should check if `J5` contains a valid number to prevent runtime errors.

A small hint: When dealing with row and column numbers in VBA, always use datatype `long`.

Comment: Thank you, so obvious and works perfect. I've changed to long. Thanks for the advice!